# Connect to Remote Host using ssh in Shell Script

Tags: linux, ssh

I am trying to connect to a remote host from a local host using SSH and all I want to do using a shell script. I can do it with `ssh hostname` but the problem is for all hosts finger prints are being asked. I don't think key gen will be helpful as everytime it will be combination of new hosts. So how can I pass finger prints so that connection can be established.

-- Baadsah

Answer (score 1):

Google has lots of results for skipping key verification:

https://www.google.com/search?q=ssh+skip+key+verification&aq=f&oq=ssh+skip+key+verification&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l2.5626j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

http://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2008/10/how-to-disable-ssh-host-key-checking.html